# Alfresco backup and restore alf_data

Tags: mysql, tomcat, deserialization, alfresco

**I have installed alfresco version 2.1 and I already had backup file folder alf_data and database sql script alfresco.sql.**

So what I did was:

1. Took backup from a different machine having a windows xp and tomcat 5.5 installed
2. Took backup of the database in the form of script named alfresco.sql
3. Then I copied that alf_data in another machine having winXP with tomcat 5.5
4. Changed the directory address from C:/..catalina../alf_data to D:/alf_data where I copied the folder
5. Than I restored the database by running the script in mysql.

NOTE:Encoding is not a problem I think because I have also tried to
synchronise encoding to UTF8.

Now after doing all this stuff I am stuck on with following error in catalina.out that the context cannot be started:

> **could not deserialize Problem !!!**

```
09:49:36,104 WARN  [org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean] Could not detect RMI registry - creating new one
09:49:44,810 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] A connection to OpenOffice could not be established.
09:49:52,943 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect.
09:49:53,098 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Bypassing schema update checks.
09:50:00,410 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:634)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:579)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:114)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getPropertiesImpl(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:908)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.setProperty(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1053)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionResourceInterceptor.invoke(TransactionResourceInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:221)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.updateCurrentRepositoryDescriptor(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:260)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.access$300(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:66)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:176)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:225)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:155)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.onBootstrap(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:182)
    at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:241)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3F3F0005
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:209)
    ... 88 more
09:50:00,426 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/alfresco]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:634)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:579)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:114)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getPropertiesImpl(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:908)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.setProperty(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1053)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionResourceInterceptor.invoke(TransactionResourceInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:221)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.updateCurrentRepositoryDescriptor(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:260)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.access$300(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:66)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:176)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:225)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:155)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.onBootstrap(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:182)
    at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:241)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3F3F0005
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:209)
    ... 88 more
09:50:00,426 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/alfresco]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListener
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:634)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:579)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:114)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getPropertiesImpl(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:908)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.setProperty(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1053)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionResourceInterceptor.invoke(TransactionResourceInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:221)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.updateCurrentRepositoryDescriptor(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:260)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.access$300(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:66)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:176)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl$1.execute(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:225)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:155)
    at org.alfresco.repo.descriptor.DescriptorServiceImpl.onBootstrap(DescriptorServiceImpl.java:182)
    at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:241)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3F3F0005
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:209)
    ... 88 more
```

Comment: Alfresco v2.1 is insanely old. Is there a very very good reason why you're not using a more modern version?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr because the backup is from the 2.x version.

Comment: @TahirMalik Mysql Version: 5.5

Comment: afaik Alfresco 2.1 was MySQL 5.0...maybe that's the problem. Did it run with 5.5 before?

Comment: @alfrescian According to my executive.Yes

Comment: did you start your java process with the correct -Dfile.encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work. Since 5.5 they changed the ENGINE type in SQL queries. So I guess your .sql import didn't went well. So just install the old DB to test this.